# Tensorflow initializing in Python without being imported

Tags: python, tensorflow

Ever since I installed Tensorflow, it keeps initializing every time I run a Python file, even if Tensorflow is not imported in it. I only know that because it always shows this error on Terminal:

> W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
> 2022-03-31 20:33:35.230201: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

The problem is it takes some time before it starts running the actual file, which can be a pain in the bottom when you want to keep testing and running a file multiple times.

Can anyone help me with this?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A library dynamically searches for the correct CUDA version in tensorflow and, if it doesn't find it, emits the warning (The **W** in the beginning stands for warnings, errors have an **E** (or **F** for fatal errors) and falls back to CPU-only mode. This is also written in the log as an info message right after the warning.

- If you don't have a CUDA-enabled GPU on your machine, or if you don't
  care about not having GPU acceleration, no need to worry.
- If, on the other hand, you installed tensorflow and wanted GPU
  acceleration, check if your CUDA version is compatible with the tensorflow version from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

If you just want to suppress warnings, you can do it with the code below:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' 
import tensorflow as tf
```

With the help of `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'`  all the INFO and WARNING messages will not be printed.

```
0 = all messages are logged (default behavior)
1 = INFO messages are not printed
2 = INFO and WARNING messages are not printed
3 = INFO, WARNING, and ERROR messages are not printed
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my problem is not the error in itself - as I mentioned in my Question, my problem is that I didn't import Tensorflow but it keeps initializing

Comment: Could you please let us know what is the platform you are using and the steps you have followed to install Tensorflow. Also could you share the code that you were trying to execute? so that we can help you better. Thanks!

Comment: I have Windows 10. Python 3.9.2. 
After some testing I found out that this happens only when I import Spacy, no matter what the code is, even if it's just `print('something')`
I installed Spacy and Tensorflow through pip if i remember correctly (`pip install tensorflow`)